# <embed> - src from proxy server

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, python-3.x, django

I am currently struggling with setting the `src` attribute of the `<embed>` element. I have my PDF documents stored in the cloud storage with limited access. My application has users, and each user has its own set of PDF contracts on the dedicated namespace.

Since I do not want to expose any URL to the users nor call the storage from the front end, I prepared a proxy endpoint (with authorized access) that returns the *application/pdf* response to be displayed in a particular `<embed>` component.

Does anyone know how to display the content with this paradigm?

Thank you for any hint.

Comment: rewrite URL on server-side. [nginx rewrite](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nginx-rewrite-url-rules)

Comment: Not the solution - I am struggling with the fact that the src attribute of the embed cannot target my backend since it requires an authorization token.